# Android Compose HorizontalPager drag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I open another screen by dragging it in HorizonPager, the logic of the screen other than the opened screen is also executed. How can I fix this problem?

```kotlin
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0) { 4 }
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState
) { page ->
    when (page) {
        0 -> {
            PostScreen()
        }
        1 -> {
            ImageScreen()
        }
        2 -> {
            VideoScreen()
        }
        3 -> {
            MyInfoScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: other screen meanin,ing If you are at 0. Page at 1,2 and 3 are all oaded?

Comment: Page load is done when entering the page.